# A local or parameter named 'Result' cannot be declared in this scope (Error CS0136)

Tags: c#

I am learning c# and I'm trying to make a program that calculate the champions winrate in (lol) League of Legends and I'm stuck with this problem:

The error is:

> Error CS0136  A local or parameter named 'Result' cannot be declared in
> this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to
> define a local or parameter

Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double TeemoWinRate = 51.33;
            double AkaliWinRate = 47.56;
            double YasuoWinRate = 49.73;
            double KhazixWinRate = 50.94;
            double YoneWinRate = 47.84;
            double LuxWinRate = 50.50;
            double MorgWinRater = 50.83;
            double TrandyWinRate = 48.50;
            double GarenWinRate = 50.50;

            double TeemoGold = 11.113;
            double AkaliGold = 10.880;
            double YasuoGold = 11.828;
            double KhazixGold = 11.541;
            double YoneGold = 11.650;
            double LuxGold = 9.497;
            double MorgGold = 8.990;
            double TrandyGold = 12.182;
            double GarenGold = 11.609;

            double Te = TeemoWinRate;
            double A = AkaliWinRate;
            double Y = YasuoWinRate;
            double K = KhazixWinRate;
            double Yo = YoneWinRate;
            double L = LuxWinRate;
            double M = MorgWinRater;
            double Tr = TrandyWinRate;
            double G = GarenWinRate;



            Console.WriteLine("Champions Ranked WinRate From the list below");
            Console.WriteLine("Akali, " +
                "Yasuo, " +
                "Khazix, " +
                "Yone, " +
                "Lux, " +
                "Morg, " +
                "Trandy, " +
                "Garen, " +
                "Teemo.");
            Console.WriteLine("Note: get sure that names are written as the list");

            Console.Write("Enter Champion Name : ");

            string Champion = Console.ReadLine();
            
            //------------------------------First if stattement--------------------------------------------
            if (Champion == "Akali")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Akali WinRate is: " + AkaliWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + AkaliGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Yasuo")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yasuo WinRate is: " + YasuoWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + YasuoGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Khazix")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Khazix WinRate is: " + KhazixWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + KhazixGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Yone")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yone WinRate is: " + YoneWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + YoneGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Lux")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lux WinRate is: " + LuxWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + LuxGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Morg")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Morg WinRate is:" + MorgWinRater + " " + "Total Gold: " + MorgGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Trandy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trandy WinRate is: " + TrandyWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + TrandyGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Garen")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Garen WinRate is: " + GarenWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + GarenGold);
            }
            else if (Champion == "Teemo")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Teemo WinRate is" + TeemoWinRate + " " + "Total Gold: " + TeemoGold);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the name Exactly as in the list.");
                return;
            }
      

            Console.WriteLine("what champion do u want to Compare with other champs");
            Console.WriteLine("Type " +
                "\n 1 for (Teemo) " +
                "\n 2 for (Akali) " +
                "\n 3 for (Yasuo) " +
                "\n 4 for (khazix) " +
                "\n 5 for (Yone) " +
                "\n 6 for (Lux)" +
                "\n 7 for (Morg)" +
                "\n 8 for (Trandy)" +
                "\n 9 for (Garen)");
            Console.Write("First Champion: ");
            double Answer1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Second Champion");
            double Answer2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            

            //------------------------------Second if stattement--------------------------------------------
            if (Answer1 == 1)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 1 + Te;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 2)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 2 + A;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 3)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 3 + Y;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 4)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 4 + K;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 5)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 5 + Yo;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 6)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 6 + L;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 7)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 7 + M;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 8)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 8 + Tr;
            }
            if (Answer1 == 9)
            {
                object Result = Answer1 - 9 + G;
            }
            //-----------------------------------Third if Statement--------------------------
            if (Answer2 == 1)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 1 + Te;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 2)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 2 + A;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 3)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 3 + Y;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 4)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 4 + K;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 5)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 5 + Yo;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 6)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 6 + L;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 7)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 7 + M;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 8)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 8 + Tr;
            }
            if (Answer2 == 9)
            {
                object Result2 = Answer2 - 9 + G;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not define `Result` more than once. Even though “you” know that only ONE (1) `if` statement will execute, the compiler doesn’t know this and assumes the code may enter “any or all” of the `if` statements. Therefore, the compiler is complaining about this multiple definition. Define the variable before the `if` statements  `object Result = null;` then in each `if` statement below, remove the `Object` definition… `Result = Answer1 - 1 + Te;`. Or string a bunch of `if/else` statements, OR use a `Case/Switch` statement. Same idea is going to apply to `Result2`.

Comment: oh it seem i forgot that i can declare it outside the if statement and use it without declaring it every time, thank you sir.

Comment: Consider changing all but the first `if` (for each variable) to `else if`. Also ask yourself - why bother setting `Result2` and then doing nothing with it?

Answer (score -1):

The error says that you cannot use `Result` since it is being used somewhere else try renaming it.

Comment: The suggestion would solve the issue, however, it won't improve the coding quality of the author. Every `Result` has to be renamed differently that would make the code have a poor quality.